# Where my fileicons in chromium gone?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, chromium

Having the problem with chromium 17.0.963.79 that the fileicons in the downloadmanager are missing. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 Unity with it's default theme and icons. How can i fix this?

Screenshot of missing icon: http://www.picbutler.de/bild/247099/missingicon53no4.png

Answer (score 2):

Solution is quiet simple. You have to install additional icon set:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full
```